# Connecting to OracleDB via Node OracleDB module on EC2

Tags: node.js, oracle, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble getting a connection established to my OracleDB that resides on a different system. From what I've learned from the [Oracledb Node module Documentation](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#connectionhandling), the connection setup should look like this:

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "welcome",
    connectString : "localhost/XE"
  }
  //fun querying goes here
```

I've reviewed the oracledb module documentation, however I cannot seem to find the syntax by which I need to follow when given certain variables. In order for me to secure a connection to the DB, I need to provide on the connection:

```
dbUserID: blah blah (maps to 'user' in Object),
dbPassword: Blahblahblah (maps to 'password' in Object),
oraclePort: (1521 as standard, but not sure where this goes in the object),
dbHostName: db.server.com (maps to 'localhost' in Object),
dbInstance: DBINSTANCENAME (not sure where this goes in object)
```

I'm fairly certain the hostname, port and instance are to be used in the 'connectString' section of the object, however I'm unsure how it should be formatted.

Any help and suggestions on how I might go about getting myself connected would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Im also receiving this error when the server is started up for the first time: `[Error: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified]` I thought I had solved this error but apparently I have not! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   oracledb.getConnection(
      {
        user          : "hr",
        password      : "welcome",
        connectString : "db.server.com:1521/DBINSTANCENAME"
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this, however it results in this error: [Error: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist]

Comment: Are you sure its actually db.server.com? I figured that is a placeholder as it seems pretty strange for a db hostname. Ditto for DBINSTANCENAME.

Comment: all of the values I used above were just placeholders for the actual values. the formatting of the hostname for the DB "test.test.com" is the same as the actual hostname being used. The instance name as well is just a placeholder

Comment: Are you able to ping that host?

Comment: Yes, host is running and there's also 0% packet loss when pinging.

Comment: Are you able to connect to that database using any other means? Such as oracle's own application (I forget what it's called)?

Comment: Yes, I am able to make connections through other means. The DB is also hosted on separate server. Not suer if I already mentioned that but figured I'd reference it now.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and I can confirm that my DB is running and the params passed to getConnection are correct. Are there some environment variables that are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'lsnrctl services' on the DB server to check the service names available.  The "Easy Connect" syntax uses the service name, not an instance name.

Check you have the right ports open.